# PHP shell_exec('whoami; ls /var/lib/nagios3 2>&1'); Permissions denied whilst fine in shell

Tags: php, shell, file-permissions

I have a little PHP script, running in a Vagrant VM (shouldn't matter, but who knows):

```
<?php
  echo 'euid' + posix_geteuid(); // Prints 33, which is the ID of www-data
  echo shell_exec('whoami; ls /var/lib/nagios3 2>&1'); // Prints www-data ls: cannot open directory /var/lib/nagios3
  echo shell_exec( 'whoami' ); // Prints www-data
?>
```

/var/lib/nagios3 looks like this:

```
drwxr-x---  4 nagios  nagios   4096 Jan  6 18:00 nagios3/
```

www-data is a member of the group nagios, I set that up.

And if I run this in the shell:

```
ssh www-data@10.0....
$ cd /var/lib/nagios3
$ ls
retention.dat  rw  spool
$ ls /var/lib/nagios3
retention.dat  rw  spool
```

Everything is just fine!

Can anybody please explain me this odd behaviour? I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Does the shell_exec call work if you remove the redirect from the command?

Comment: If I do, nothing is printed. No folders, no nothing. I assume this is because output is written to stderr.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but I don't suppose you've checked to make sure that whatever distro you've got on the VM doesn't have some SELinux rule that's stepping on your ties?

Comment: I have the standard vagrant precise64 box. There is nothing like selinux under /etc. Is there anything else I should check to make sure this can't be the reason?

Comment: All I can think of is checking your logs for selinux, OH! And/or apparmor, because I've had similar problems in the past. It's been too long since I last came across it to tell you exactly where to look, though - now I disable either/both as soon as I turn a new one up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check what `id` says, does it list nagios in the groups for www-data?

```
echo shell_exec('id'); // uid=33(web-data) gid=... groups=... IS nagios IN HERE?
```

If you added www-data to group nagios *after* starting the webserver, you might need to restart the webserver, or even reboot. At least this happens with normal user sessions in Linux - you add yourself to some group (audio/video etc) and need to logout/login before the change takes place. When you ssh into the box you are given a fresh shell with the new permissions, but the webserver is still running under the old permissions.

Comment: Sometimes solutions are sooo simple. I didn't think about the old shell. I already checked that with id by myself after I asked the question here, that wasn't an issue. Then I rebooted my machine and now it works. A big thank you to you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give 775 permission to that php file

```
chmod 775
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it didn't help unfortunately.